# Issue with complex TypeScript union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have a function that filters some data from a server, based off of an array of options (an HTML `select` sort of thing). However, in some versions of the function I have all the data from the server from the get-go, and other times I only have part of the data. When I only have partial data, I want the filter's `options` array to be objects with `content` (what's rendered on the screen) and `optionKey` (which I send to the server for it to do the filtering). When I have the full data, I want the filter's `options` array to be objects with `content`, `optionKey`, and a `filter` function , that corresponds to a specific key of the filtered data. I scoured online and found a solution that works pretty well for me:

```js
type HasPartialData = {
  options: ({ content: string; optionKey: string })[];
};

type HasFullData<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: {
    columnKey: K;
    options: ({ content: string; optionKey: string; filter: (value: T[K], row: T) => boolean })[];
  };
}[keyof T];

type FilterProps<T> = (
  | ({
    hasPartial: true;
  } & HasPartialData)
  | ({
    hasPartial: false;
  } & HasFullData<T>)
);
```

However, I've run into a problem. I have a function (`FilterMap`) that receives a `hasPartial` flag and an array of either `HasPartialData` or `HasFullData<T>`, depending on the `hasPartial` flag:

```js
type FilterMapProps<T> = (
  | {
    filters: HasPartialData[];
    hasPartial: true;
  }
  | {
    filters: HasFullData<T>[];
    hasPartial: false;
  }
);
```

But when I try to pass this to the `Filter` function, TypeScript can't tell that they're "synced up" and that passing them should work.

My original attempt was this:

```js
function FilterMap<T>(props: FilterMapProps<T>) {
  return props.filters.map((filter) => {
    return Filter({ ...filter, hasPartial: props.hasPartial });
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
}
```

But it causes this TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '(HasFullData<T> & { hasPartial: boolean; }) | { hasPartial: boolean; options: { content: string; optionKey: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterProps<T>'.
    Type '{ hasPartial: boolean; options: { content: string; optionKey: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FilterProps<T>'.
      Type '{ hasPartial: boolean; options: { content: string; optionKey: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ hasPartial: true; } & HasPartialData'.
        Type '{ hasPartial: boolean; options: { content: string; optionKey: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ hasPartial: true; }'.
          Types of property 'hasPartial' are incompatible.
            Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.(2345)
```

So I tried this:

```js
  if (props.hasPartial) {
    return props.filters.map((filter) => {
      return Filter({ ...filter, hasPartial: props.hasPartial });
    });
  } else {
    return props.filters.map((filter) => {
      return Filter({ ...filter, hasPartial: props.hasPartial });
    });
  }
```

...which worked, but I think it's really ugly.

The only solution I felt kind of OK with was:

```js
return props.filters.map((filter) => {
  return Filter({ ...filter as any, hasPartial: props.hasPartial });
});
```

But I don't like this use of `as any`...

Here's a full example in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=64&ssc=5&pln=62&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwApwE7AJZwDYBE7BxQC8UA3gFBRQD2YmNAdggFxQAUZUAxk8BI2BsEwVBkYBzANy16GJgGkIIYaPESoAXwCUAbQC6UipqMVQkWIgBiAV2x4CcADwAVAHwlyVKLoVRxUADWyjQAZlAu+gC0APxslNTUvNg2ALaMSipQCkaJsgzMbJw8fAJCUCJikjJ0BZmqVdJQoRjY-KhFAG44NhBsLr76ADRQqDQA7v3aJB4ARjQ02BBwjFp6ht4mxrrBIGERG2bg0Fat7UhjYAiuHqTs3gA+HAmJABaIKOhY2GyivblaKAAMksyDQmBw+EI2kez281HeYK+ODYoRwCAgAM0wNBtnsUOc7hh2lMoRsjG4BSgpzaEFQN3YYEurGpZzpFzo1yJXmoqAgwBsqFWjDs2BkAHpxRUaKloNgaBIMNwoBIaOpaKsAq86RBjBQjhYae0ALJwMAcq43Tz3ahPF7UFq01As+BIiEOQgGAEIj7g76-VD-Taw+3NNnOtiuvEewluL3wqCIz7u1HozHBkn6skUqlGummsAMpmcth51AFi1ctzTF6SqDAV4YBBQcY0VCBBAjWY2YBQACSo2W9hAUAAJkwAOS97AYYL+XtRfsT1JQGftHDYEcAKxsIhKYBA6t4o4gQ28dZWo-rjebGIgqWbYDVgiWCAQ56lGHCjOZADok36OA1h+iR8gKQpQMWVy-o67QIL+qRmuw7CwXS0zEB4tZSnkYGCqsZbFL+RGoagIwAciPyQX+5HumsAJ1tQOj0VK2IQNgGI8lADGDuBqxQfBJHwYhYDISR6GYSBOH8nhrJOoRxHhmRvoUWw-H-sptFMZJdEgZo+rUHWDZNjwcC7hAzbmOZ3BiPQ9Y0FAdJjB0IG4RBamCQhSEoeG4mcdxrn4eG8kwYpiYaf6VGcupbrfGsumZgZUoAHopalaXpRlmVZVlIEAIKoBIaRlLQ4SWVAE7sFGooElaIJcDREXzIsyyMDIOhQHaYUxSiUBNUsKw1HITAslwvCCGUDTqINdTKJN1RaF6WgTv4zaMDQvaIAgGASIwcCzEsdmQWgcCyu0JX1sc5VlpWNwTr+2kuJdE71eFPV9S103yIU5AlONghzU0tRffUFRqPNmiLZoy3GWtG1vttu37dAwD2WVE7Xcyt33YleQRE9L3dZR70DfkX0jb9-D-aDjSfYos3U1NC2GEtK1QLDUCbQje0HSjF0WM9XXJhFfyYoCIKukLkKOHd2l5I9-ME5LRMLP1rWk8N8QUxNDPzUDdNZJUjMQ8zUOs+znM7dzyOo-jguAZRIttTLOO44k8vmedUF0qA5UNTgy1oNA4i8KkYAEBgSPY1x2Gu27T3E4w0OretHPw5bSOHWjIt3ewABMADMAAsACsMIgZeYa7cOUCLkZzatu2na9T2-ZjpOvZ8huI4znOu7qgABogHOMCA-dEVHAWRdBHnCaJPkzJxvLSRBBFcOPJGp8PIBKYTqnUa92A6YxMJ6RQdZ9hOnTQOi9ncNq3DBFeDYENexlNonvazBA3CmRx+wNtAfuwl+4sANNAAAwvfQIfZQgFj7AgFw2p4EIF6DddwngXiCUjAfAk8YfS73rIGdM2I7TeCwbiaqjgbh4LtipZoaYjCn2zJSL6UBIHf2gbAs08DEEQGQb0IszI2DsIfjAuBCCkFvlQZjbkZAmHkhYUwCI5lMCSEESWWSJozRoOrH5KUdc27mQ-i2NsgRQE40niIzh4jeH8IgD+TkmYQLdl7AY8c5lx4gS-BwNSftsDARdkvXibCoFiO4RIvhUj7H8QStHQEbEOJYSksEqxYSwA8MkSg6JzJYl1j0poIAA).

I really want a way to do this without the ugly `if` statement and without `as any`... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide an extra generic parameter to capture the `Partial`ness of each type:

```js
type HasData<T, Partial extends boolean> = (
  Partial extends true
    ? HasPartialData
    : HasFullData<T>
)

type FilterProps<T, Partial extends boolean> = (
    HasData<T, Partial> & { hasPartial: Partial }
);

type FilterMapProps<T, Partial extends boolean> = (
  { filters: HasData<T, Partial>[], hasPartial: Partial }
);
```

etc

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5AP5N)